# Specify countdown timer duration with uitextfield entry

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on my second app, learning Swift. My first was a calculator that output some results based on a number of UITextField inputs when a button was pressed.

I have now made a countdown timer, working through an online tutorial.

How can I set the duration ("seconds" variable) using the number entered in the UITextField? I have tried using

```
var seconds = Double(timeSetupField.text!)!
```

in the place of

```
var seconds = 60
```

but I understand that this does not work but I am not totally sure why. The property initialisers run before 'self' is available, but I am not using "self." - I suspect I have misunderstood something. Usage of variables is a bit more complicated than my simple calculator.

Any suggestions for how to get this implemented would be great, and any explanation to the above question also much appreciated.

Code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CountdownTimer
//
//  Created by Matt Baines on 01/09/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Matt Baines. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // PROPERTIES
    @IBOutlet weak var timeSetupField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeCountdownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

    // DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
    // This variable will hold a starting value of seconds.
    var seconds = 60
    // Timer variable
    var timer = Timer()
    //This will be used to make sure only one timer is created at a time.
    var isTimerRunning = false
    // For pause & resume
    var resumeTapped = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Disable pause button so it is not visible until a time is started.
        pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector:(#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isTimerRunning = true
        pauseButton.isEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if seconds < 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
        } else {
            // This will decrement the seconds.
            seconds -= 1
            // This will update the label.
            timeCountdownLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
        }
    }

    func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        let hours = Int(time) / 3600
        let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(time) % 60
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }

    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isTimerRunning == false {
            runTimer()
            self.startButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.resumeTapped == false {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.resumeTapped = true
            self.pauseButton.setTitle("Resume", for: .normal)
        } else {
            runTimer()
            self.resumeTapped = false
            self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        timer.invalidate()
        // Manually enter the restarting point for the seconds
        seconds = 60
        timeCountdownLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
        isTimerRunning = false
        // Ensure pause button text is set back to pause
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        pauseButton.isEnabled = false
        startButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: “but I am not using "self."” yes you are. `timeSetupField` is `self.timeSetupField`.

Comment: “How can I set the duration ("seconds" variable) using the number entered in the UITextField?” Unclear. When exactly did you want to do that?

Comment: @matt i believe he is trying to store the value of the textfield's text in `seconds`.

Comment: Sorry! I have currently coded in the duration of the countdown timer as 60 seconds. I have a uitextfield which I intend the user to use to specify the number of seconds they want to the timer to count down for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to replace the line of code

```
var seconds = 60
```

with

```
var seconds = Double(timeSetupField.text!)!
```

up top where you are declaring variables? If this is the case this is where your problem lies.

"Self", meaning the view controller, has not loaded in until viewDidLoad. You cannot access your IBOutlets until the view has loaded in. You are trying to grab information from an IBOutlet which "doesn't exist" yet.

If in your storyboard you already have some text set on your timeSetupField you can do something like this :

```
//Global Variables
var seconds = 60

//Life cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    // Checks to make sure the timeSetupField.text isn't nil. If it is nil, you will not run any more code within viewDidLoad which prevents a crash on the next line if timeFromTextField is nil. 
    guard let timeFromTextField = timeSetupField.text else { return }
    seconds = timeFromTextField
}
```

At this point your views are loaded in and timeSetupField.text is available to access. You can globally declare seconds with a default value so you can access it everywhere in the ViewController file, but set the value in ViewDidLoad after the outlet is available.

You can safely change your seconds variable from any functions within your code like an IBAction or perhaps a function that gets called when you hit enter on the keyboard in this case.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense. I am still getting familiar with how these apps work. I am used MATLAB and GUIDE GUIs. I'll try it tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: @13aines Haha no worries. Figuring out where to put globals and when / where things are usable took me a while to get used to. Let me know if you need any more help with this! 

I've added an edit for how to more safely use your timeSetupField value as well. You want to avoid force unwrapping with ! as much as possible, even though in this case you should know if there is a default value in the text field from your storyboard. 

Good luck

Comment: You don't need to safely unwrap `UITextField` text. It always returns a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a good start but the code can be improved by separating the timer logic and view controller code - that will make the timer easier to test and it allow you to reuse it elsewhere. The code below is incomplete but it works and will get you started on separating your UI and logic. Good luck on your second app!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeSetupField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeCountdownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    var seconds = 60
    var timer: SecondsTimer?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updateTimeLabel(newSeconds: 60)
    }

    func updateTimeLabel(newSeconds: Int) {
        let hours = newSeconds / 3600
        let minutes = newSeconds / 60 % 60
        let seconds = newSeconds % 60
        let timeStr = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
        timeCountdownLabel.text = timeStr
        timeCountdownLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        timer = SecondsTimer.init(callback: timerUpdate)
        timer?.start(initialSeconds: 60)
        self.startButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    private func timerUpdate(seconds: Int) {
        if seconds > 0 {
            updateTimeLabel(newSeconds: seconds)
        } else {
            timer?.stop()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let timer = timer else { return }
        if timer.paused {
            pauseButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        } else {
            pauseButton.setTitle("Resume", for: .normal)
        }
        pauseButton.sizeToFit()
        timer.paused = !timer.paused
    }

    @IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        timer?.reset()
        updateTimeLabel(newSeconds: 60)
    }

}

class SecondsTimer: NSObject {
    var paused = false
    var stopReqest = false
    var seconds = 0
    let callback: (Int)->()

    init(callback: @escaping (Int)->()) {
        self.callback = callback
        super.init()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SecondsTimer.applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SecondsTimer.applicationWillResignActiveNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
        print("timer deinit")
    }

    func start(initialSeconds: Int = 60) {
        paused = false
        stopReqest = false
        seconds = initialSeconds
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.deccrementSeconds), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func reset() {
        seconds = 60
    }

    func stop() {
        stopReqest = true
    }

    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification() {
        paused = false
    }

    @objc func applicationWillResignActiveNotification() {
        paused = true
    }

    @objc func deccrementSeconds(timer: Timer)  {
        if stopReqest {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }
        if paused == false {
            seconds -= 1
            callback(seconds)
        }
    }

}
```